# How to export specific column from specific table from database in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to add two specific column's data in another table's columns using same database in phpmyadmin. I know the way to solve this using .CSV file but anyone help me to figure out this without using .CSV file. How i can export that two specific column's data from one table and import that in another table using same database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO new_table (field1, field2)
  SELECT field1, field2
  FROM old_table
```